# How i can receive the size of the requests with asyncio in python

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio

I need to know how much Mbytes per second there are in the request with is sent with asyncio in python. I tried with resp.read() or with resp.content.read() but it isn't working.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def get_requests(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            result = resp
    return result 


big_urls = ['http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com']
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coroutines = [get_requests(url) for url in big_urls]
results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*coroutines))
print(results)
```

Comment: please fix the code in your question to a simple working code example

Comment: Are you unable to get the contents of the response, or do you not know how to calculate the download speed from the contents? Do you need the download speed of the server's response or the upload speed of your request?

Comment: I need the size of the request in Mbytes.

Comment: Have you tried something like `return len(await resp.read())`? When you say that something "isn't working", you should describe how it isn't working, exactly (does it just hang? does it raise an exception?) and attach relevant information, such as the exception stack trace.

Comment: I'm sorry for inaccurate description. I am new here and also in the programming. I have tried with len(resp.read()) and the error was: TypeError: object of type 'coroutine' has no len(). 
Now I tried with return len(await resp.read()) and it's working well. Thanks!